# c# interop: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I am writing a c# program to access settings from the Window File History system. Since I couldn't find a COM wrapper for the dll (fhcfg.dll) I'm trying to write my own...and I've done almost no interop programming.

I'm following the instructions at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa645736%28v=vs.94%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

Here are the class and interface definitions I've written (the GUIDs come from FhCfg.h):

```
[ComImport, Guid("ED43BB3C-09E9-498a-9DF6-2177244C6DB4")]
public class FHManager
{
}

[ Guid( "6A5FEA5B-BF8F-4EE5-B8C3-44D8A0D7331C" ), InterfaceType( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual ) ]
public interface IFHManager
{
    void LoadConfiguration();

    void CreateDefaultConfiguration( [ In ] bool overwriteIfExists );

    void SaveConfiguration();

    void AddRemoveExcludeRule(
        [ In ] bool add,
        [ In ] ProtectedItemCategory category,
        [ Out, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.BStr ) ]
        string item
    );

    void GetIncludeExcludeRules(
        [ In ] bool include,
        [ In ] ProtectedItemCategory category,
        [ Out ] IntPtr iterator
    );

    void GetLocalPolicy(
        [ In ] LocalPolicy localPolicy,
        [ Out ] ulong policyValue
    );

    void SetLocalPolicy(
        [ In ] LocalPolicy localPolicy,
        [ In ] ulong policyValue
    );

    void GetBackupStatus( [ Out ] BackupStatus status );

    void SetBackupStatus( [ In ] BackupStatus status );

    void GetDefaultTarget( [ Out ] IntPtr target );

    void ValidateTarget( [ In, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.BStr ) ]
        string url, [ Out ] ValidationResult validationResult );

    void ProvisionAndSetNewTarget(
        [ In, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.BStr ) ]
        string url,
        [ In, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.BStr ) ]
        string name
    );

    void ChangeDefaultTargetRecommendation( [ In ] bool recommend );

    void QueryProtectionStatus(
        [ Out ] int protectionState,
        [ Out, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.BStr ) ]
        string protectedUntilTime
    );
}
```

I defined these based on the definitions in FhCfg.h, with a couple of substitutions of IntPtrs for pointers to iterators (which I'm not sure how to handle correctly, but since I'm not using those methods I figured it didn't matter).

The only method I'm interested in using for now is GetLocalPolicy().

The various enums I just rewrote in c#, assuming that in both c++ and c# they'd be based on ints by default.

The code I'm using to exercise GetLocalPolicy() is a Net Core console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FHManager fhm = new FHManager();
        var junk = fhm as IFHManager;

        ulong value = 0;
        junk.GetLocalPolicy( LocalPolicy.Frequency, value);
    }
}
```

The ArgumentException ("Value does not fall within the expected range") is thrown by the junk.GetLocalPolicy() line.

In addition to wanting to understand what's causing the exception I'm getting, I'd be interested in learning of a simpler/more foolproof way of dealing with accessing unmanaged code when there's no pre-defined type lib.

**Followup**

Thanx to the great feedback provided I was able to get the code to work.

For the benefit of others, there was a second problem lurking in the code: you have to call LoadConfiguration() on the interface before GetLocalPolicy() can succeed (i.e., GetLocalPolicy() works on a "hidden" instance of the configuration object, which you have to load first).

I did have some followup questions, though:

- When defining the COM interface in c#, is it done positionally --
  method 1 in the interface definition must match method 1 declared in
  the c++ header file -- or is it done by name? I had assumed it was by
  name, but the answer (to me) seems to imply otherwise.
- If the c++ method declaration contains a single [out] parameter, can the c#
  interface method be declared with that parameter as the method's
  return value, or do you need to declare it as an out parameter?

BTW, I'd also like to thank Hans Passant for his helpful answer/explanation...which I would happily accept as "the" answer, except that it appears to have vanished.

Comment: The main issue is you define `InterfaceIsDual` (for interfaces deriving from IDispatch) while it should be `InterfaceIsIUnknown`. Also, instead of using `[Out]` annotation, just use C#'s `out` keyword: `void GetLocalPolicy(FH_LOCAL_POLICY_TYPE localPolicy, out ulong policyValue);`

Comment: Thanx, @SimonMourier. I'd be interested in your thoughts on the followup questions in my edit.

Comment: COM is a binary standard, so only methods orders and signatures (argument order, type, etc.) matter, names are for humans. Yes, you can declare out parameter as the return value most of the time. PS: Hans (Passant) has deleted his answer.